# How to get list of all un-selected row index in JqWidgets grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqwidget

I am trying to get list of all un-selected row index in jqwidgets grid. As there is a predefined method to get list of all selected row index:

```
var allSelectedVals=[];

var rowindexes = jQuery('#userProfiles').jqxGrid('getselectedrowindexes');

for (var i = 0; i < rowindexes.length; i++) 
{
  var data = jQuery('#userProfiles').jqxGrid('getrowdata', rowindexes[i]);
  allSelectedVals.push(data.userId);
}

alert('allSelectedVals: ' + allSelectedVals);
```

Is there any similar approach for getting un-selected row index also?

I will appreciate all your help to get it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not built-in method for this purpose, so I've wrote simple possible  function here it is: we get total row count, and removing all ids from selected items (selected items are calculated upon selection, not when calling this method, thus does not take any meaning effort).

Here is the method:

```
function getUnselectedIndexes(selector)
{
    var selectedIndexes = $(selector).jqxGrid('getselectedrowindexes');

    var meta = $(selector).jqxGrid('getdatainformation');
    var total = meta.rowscount;

    var unSelectedIndexes = new Array();

    for (i = 0; i < total; i++)
    {
        if (selectedIndexes.indexOf(i) !== -1) 
        {
            continue;
        }

        unSelectedIndexes.push(i);
    }

    console.log(unSelectedIndexes);

    return unSelectedIndexies;
}
```

And you can get all unselected indexes by calling it this way:

```
getUnselectedIndexes("#userProfiles");
```

Answer (score 1):

The "getboundrows" method of [jQWidgets Grid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm?(arctic)) returns all rows - Example:

```
 var data = generatedata(5);
 var source = {
     localdata: data,
     datafields: [{
         name: 'firstname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'lastname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'productname',
         type: 'string'
     }, {
         name: 'date',
         type: 'date'
     }, {
         name: 'quantity',
         type: 'number'
     }, {
         name: 'price',
         type: 'number'
     }],
     datatype: "array"
 };

 var adapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
 $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
     width: 600,
     height: 100,
     theme: 'energyblue',
     source: adapter,
     sortable: true,
     selectionmode: 'singlecell',
     columns: [{
         text: 'First Name',
         datafield: 'firstname',
         columngroup: 'Name',
         width: 90
     }, {
         text: 'Last Name',
         columngroup: 'Name',
         datafield: 'lastname',
         width: 90
     }, {
         text: 'Product',
         datafield: 'productname',
         width: 170
     }, {
         text: 'Order Date',
         datafield: 'date',
         width: 160,
         cellsformat: 'dd-MMMM-yyyy'
     }, {
         text: 'Quantity',
         datafield: 'quantity',
         width: 80,
         cellsalign: 'right'
     }, {
         text: 'Unit Price',
         datafield: 'price',
         cellsalign: 'right',
         cellsformat: 'c2'
     }]
 });

 $("#jqxbutton").jqxButton({
     theme: 'energyblue',
     width: 200,
     height: 30
 });

 $('#jqxbutton').click(function () {
     var rows = $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('getboundrows');
     var result = "";
     for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
         var row = rows[i];
         result += row.firstname + " " + row.lastname + " " + row.productname + " " + row.date + " " + row.quantity + " " + row.price + "\n";
     }
     alert(result);
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/3LLVW/. Having the indexes of the selected rows, you can loop through the rows and check whether the row's boundindex is within the rowIndexes Array. If it's not, then the row is not selected.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/yzqswcvr/

Comment: yeah I can do it man by implementing my own logic (but it cost me performance).. what I am trying to ask is there any predefined method is there to achieve it... which may improve my performance. By the way thanks for your suggestion

Comment: a simple JavaScript for-loop would not hurt your performance too much, but it's your decision :)

Comment: ya that is the last solution I will do (if doesn't get any other approach)

Comment: there's unfortunately no method called getunselectedrowindexes or something like that so it seems that this is the approach which should be used.

Comment: You are wrong, when you use `.jqxGrid('getboundrows');` it returns all the data, and OP needs just indexes, which can be retrieved in a simpler way, which I've posted as answer

Comment: I do not think that I am wrong :) bound indexes and rows count are different things. I wrote the guy to use row's boundindex. I know what "getboundrows" returns :) and  I don't think that I am wrong as I know pretty well how this widget works as being part of the Team who wrote it :)

Comment: I meant you are wrong about: ` this is the approach which should be used` this, not another things, so don't get it too close. I respect your work, you are great, cheers ;)

Comment: np, but with rowscount, the sample may not work when filtering is applied. Alternative: http://jsfiddle.net/jqwidgets/yzqswcvr/